# How to connect client applications to SQL SERVER 2012 cluster?

Tags: sql-server-2012, connectivity

Following are the environment Details :

Database Server : SQL SERVER 2012
Operating System : Windows Server 2012

Single instance of SQL SERVER 2012 is installed in cluster configuration with 2 nodes. I have 3 IP addresses, one for each node of SQL SERVER and one for the cluster.

I am able to connect to this configuration by providing SQL SERVER instance name to the DataSource of connection string but i am unable to connect using cluster name as data source

so the following is working

```
<add name="Default" connectionString="Data source=SQLInstanceName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseNAme;User Id=userid;Password=password;Connection Timeout=120;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

but changing SQLInstanceName to IP address/Name of cluster does not work

```
<add name="Default" connectionString="Data source=clustername;Initial Catalog=DatabaseNAme;User Id=userid;Password=password;Connection Timeout=120;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Is this by Design?

My understanding is that client application needs to connect to cluster and not to specific instance.

Comment: No, it's not by design; you should always be connecting using the virtual address -- that's the whole point of using a cluster, which is to abstract the specific piece of hardware running the instance. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those should work. If it's a named instance, it should be:

```
DATA SOURCE=ClusterName\SQLInstanceName;
```

If it's a default instance, just:

```
DATA SOURCE=ClusterName;
```

You are always connecting to an *instance* of SQL Server, whether it is clustered or not. The cluster will know which node in the cluster is currently hosting the instance, and this should not really be a concern of yours, at least in terms of the connection string - that's kind of the whole point, a failover to a different node in the cluster should not require your application to change anything.